# Not able to get attachment from SOAP Message using SAAJ with my Springboot Servlet application

Tags: java, xml, soap, mtom, saaj

STATEMENT : Trying to send SOAP Message with attachment from client but not able to get the attachment on server side, Using SAAJ not the MTOM/XOP because I am not using WSDL file. its Spring boot Servlet which takes SOAP message as Stream and generates SOAP Message as output Stream for response.